# Java Code for the next button

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

Hi this is my java code for next button.

but it goes onto only 1 record i.e after the last record it moves to the 1st one only.

how to move it through the entire database entries.

plz provide me some suggestions.

```
public void Next() {
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        con = DBConnection();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from data", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            field1.setText(rs.getString("Name"));
            field2.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("Age")));
        } else {
            rs.previous();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(nxtbtn, "end of file");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException err) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(nxtbtn, err.getMessage());
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for betted help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable,

Comment: please for why reason is in `PreparedStatement  declared `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`

Answer (score 1):

When you call next, it reloads all the results from the database and moves the cursor to just before the first row, calling `rs.next` will move to the first row.

Do you're query once, presumably when you need to display the next record.

In your `next` method, simply call `rs.next()` to move the cursor to the next available row in the result set.

Of course, you'll need continue to manage the error states ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the `resultset` out side of the `next()` method. calling `next()` every-time resets the `resultset`, and `cursor` moves to start again.

Answer (score 0):

if understand it correctly you want to use the next button to click throup the resultset?

then you shoul read the database an have it stored in your resultset outside the next button method.

at the moment it seems that your making a new resultset with every click and only reading the first set of data.

```
private Connection con = DBConnection();
private ResultSet rs = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
public void onLoad()
{
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("YOUR-CODE-HERE");
}
```

and now in the next method go through the rs with each click

Answer (score 0):

rs.next() move the cursor to the next available row.thats why it show one record. use `while(rs.next())`

Answer (score 0):

Move one record forward like below

```
rs.next()
```

Move through all the 'next' records like below

```
while(rs.next())
```

Move back like below

```
rs.previous()
```